# Delete from MongoDB with multiple filters

Tags: c#, mongodb

Is there support for deleting collections using multiple filters in Mongo? I only have the code for deleting with 1 WHERE clause.

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(table);
await collection.FindOneAndDeleteAsync(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("MasterID", 11630));
```

There doesn't seem to be anything on their website or other forums but I was hoping someone might know a way?

Comment: You mean like `var filter = builder.Eq("address.zipcode", "10016") & builder.Eq("cuisine", "Other");` which is actually taken from the [Getting Started Guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/update/#update-multiple-documents). Basically you are putting builders together with logical expressions to form the underyling BSON document.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there a way I can load the filters from a KeyValuePair<string, string> ?

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55417118/1257607) may help as well

Answer (score 0):

If you want go full Builder way:

```
Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.And(
      Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("MasterID", 11630),
      Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Foo", "Bar"));
```

EDIT:
documentation says here that there is overload that takes IEnumerable:
http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_And_1.htm

So:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.And(myDic.Select(g => Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq(g.Key, g.Value)));
```

One liner for getting filter from key vale pairs. Courtesy of @Skami

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there a way I can load the filters from a KeyValuePair<string, string> ?

Comment: I don't have anywhere to test it atm so I am not 100% sure. Never tried it but I have a hunch it might be possible.

Comment: can you tell me. Is there overload of Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.And that takes any kind of IEnumerable or maybe array?

Comment: @134395, I believe you may be looking for this ``var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.And(myDic.Select(g => Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq(g.Key, g.Value)));`` Which pretty much does the same as above, only it's a one liner >.>